# Geometry of cubic 3-fold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm having some questions about the geometry of the cubic 3-fold. Every variety is over $\mathbb C$.

Take $Y$ a smooth cubic 3-fold in $\mathbb P^4$ and $E$ a curve of degree 6 and genus 1 contained in it. First assume it is smooth.

If i study the exact sequence $$0\to I_E(2)\to O_Y(2) \to j_*O_E(2)\to 0$$ I arrive at the conclusion that $H^0(Y,I_E(2))$ has dimension 3, and $E$ is contained in the zero locus of a section of the linear system $O_Y(2)$ that is smooth. I can compute its tangent bundle using the adjunction formula and as it is a complete intersection, I can prove that its $h^{0,1}$ is zero, and therefore it is a smooth K3 surface, let us call it $S$.

Now, I'd like to prove that $O_S(E)$ is generated by 2 sections. I belive I can compute the dimension of $H^0(S,O_S(E))$ using Riemann-Roch, but how do I get that the sections actually generate $O_S(E)$.

Thanks.

Comment: This is true for any smooth curve $E$ of genus 1 in a $K3$ surface $S$. See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717990/a-linear-system-of-a-curve-on-a-k3-surface/718076#718076 to show that $E^2=0$ and $H^0(S,O_S(E))=2$. But that means the two sections must have disjoint vanishing sets, and therefore generate the bundle.

Comment: Thank you!
To prove that $E^2=0$ implies that the two zero loci are disjoint, i need to prove that the two sections are tranverse don't I? Because otherwise, their intersection might not compute the self intersection of E.

Comment: In general you're right, but actually you don't need to worry about that here. If you have two distinct effective divisors on a surface and at least one is irreducible (as your curve $E$ is), then they intersect in finitely many points. The intersection number will then count those points (with multiplicity), so the only way it can be 0 is if the two divisors are indeed disjoint.